# HTML page is printing my closing syntax for php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to put PHP in my html code but when i run it in browser the closing syntax is listed, here is a highly simplyfied version of the code

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>
    <?php
        $names = ('TOM');
        echo $names .'<br/>';
    ?>

    </h1>
</body>
```

and when i run it the page prints ('; ?>) even if i just try to echo a simple string skipping the variable i get the same problem asif html is not recognizing the php opening tags any suggestions?

Comment: Does the file end in `.php`? Is PHP installed and configured?

Comment: did you close the <html> tag?

Comment: Is that array syntax?  $names = array('TOM');

Comment: @shapeshifter no, that would be `[]` for shorthand array.

Comment: @One it didn't. http://3v4l.org/WOPp8

Comment: Nope works fine for me too.

Comment: What is that bracket syntax called?

Comment: @shapeshifter `echo (((((((('Silly Bracket Code'))))))));`

Comment: @shapeshifter see [this](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-82) it's called short array syntax. The parentheses the OP is using should be valid as it would be the equivalent to say doing this `$var = ('0' + 1);` for instance, just without the arithmetic.

Comment: yup php is installed and working properly, i tried $names= 'TOM'; as well but no dice there and i did close the html just didn't quite grab it in the copy, the it a .html file but i thought that i could put php into as long as a opened it '<?php almost like a script tag for using js

Answer (score 1):

As is now obvious from your comment.. you can't just put php, which is server side code, into an .html file and have it evaluated as php by the server.  The parser, as far as I am aware, searches for .php files, and then acts accordingly.  Without some sort of template engine, what you are doing will not work.  Suffice to say...

Change your file to `.php`, instead of `.html`, and it should work.

Comment: You got it man, thx for everyone's time i will import my php files to html from now on thnx again for such quick responses.

Comment: @Vortechx Please then accept this answer, when you are able, by clicking on the outlined checkmark under the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try a single file with:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If that doesn't work, your server is not processing php files properly. In which case, you'll need to provide more information about the file names and the server that you're using (or are you just doing this on a local computer and double-clicking the file to open in your default browser? in which case it will not work).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set your php.ini to parse html files for php.  The downfall of this is that it can use a lot more system resources.  If its just your test server then I'd just edit the ini and add the extension.

The smartest thing would be to put the php in a separate file and just include it into the html.  In your html you'd do this:

```
< !--#include virtual="phpfile.php" -->
```

And it would load your php and parse it properly.

Comment: Thnx for all the comments but i am just going to link the php file to my html as this works flawlessly and is the best way to have full control and change options later